# Prove that for every real number $x$, if $x>2$ then there is a real number $y$ such that $y+1/y = x$.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm trying to learn about proofs and I'm stuck in Velleman's book "How to Prove it".

This is the question (ex.6 p.118):

> Prove that for every real number $x$, if $x > 2$ then there is a real number $y$ such that $y+\frac{1}{y}= x$.

I couldn't do it so I went to see the answer, and it is written that we can assume that $y=(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})/2$.

How did the author get to this value for $y$?

Comment: The provided answer is not correct. Are you sure you've written the statement correctly? Maybe you mean $y+\frac{1}{y}=x$?

Comment: yes, sorry. edited

Comment: It is enough to look at the range of the function $f(y)=y+\dfrac1y$ for $y$ positive .

Comment: quadratic formula

Comment: @Michael Another proof is that if $f(y)=y+1/y$ then $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=2$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)=\infty$ so you can apply the intermediate value theorem without having to provide an explicit $y$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that

$$y+\frac{1}{y}=x.$$

Then

$$y^2+1=xy,$$

and

$$y^2-xy+1=0.$$

It follows that

$$y=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}$$

either by completing the square, or by using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear now.

Comment: Need to argue $y$ is real.

Comment: @vonbrand I appreciate your feedback, and I've upvoted your comment. The original post asked about a problem in a book that used a particular formula: $y=\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}$. The problem from the book is quoted in the original post, but my understanding was that the point of the original post was to get an explanation of where this formula came from, and not to get a complete proof of the problem in the book. In any event $y$ is real because $x>2$, which implies that $x^2-4>0$, which implies that $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ is real, which implies that $y$ is real. Thanks for improving my answer!

Answer (score 1):

$y + \frac 1y = x \implies$

$y(y+\frac 1y) = yx \implies$

$y^2 - yx + 1 = 0$

Now we use quadratic equation or complete the square to solve for $y$.

$y = \frac {x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 4}}2$

The only issue is we must have $x^2 -4 > 0$.  Which is okay as $x \ge 2 \implies x^2 -4 \ge 0$

Answer (score -1):

The author just pulled it out of nowhere - where it comes from isn't important to the proof, only that it works. For how they knew what to pull out of nowhere, try rearranging $y + \frac{1}{y} = x$ (which I suspect is what the formula was supposed to read?) to make $x$ the subject.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. How you would re-arrange it?

Comment: Mutliply both sides by $y$ to obtain $y^2 + 1 = xy$. Get all of the $y$s together by subtracting $xy$ from both sides to get $y^2 - xy + 1 = 0$. Complete the square to obtain $(y - \frac{x}{2})^2 - \frac{x^2}{4} + 1 = 0$. Add $\frac{x^2}{4} - 1$ to both sides to obtain $(y - \frac{x}{2})^2 = \frac{x^2}{4} - 1$. Take square roots on both sides to obtain $y - \frac{x}{2} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4} - 1}$. Add $\frac{x}{2}$ to both sides to obtain $y = \frac{x}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4} - 1} = \frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{2}$, and arbitrarily chose the larger solution - the other also works.

Comment: I'd like to remind you all to keep it civil. We're all here to work together.